# Can GCP Dataproc sqoop data (or run other jobs on) from local DB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sqoop, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-vpn

Can GCP Dataproc sqoop import data from local DB to put into GCP Storage (without GCP VPC)?

We have a remote Oracle DB connected to our *local network* via VPN tunnel that we use a Hadoop cluster to extract data out of each day via *Apache Sqoop*. Would like to replace this process with GCP Dataproc cluster to run the sqoop jobs and GCP Storage.
Found this article that appears to be doing something similar [Moving Data with Apache Sqoop in Google Cloud Dataproc](https://medium.com/google-cloud/moving-data-with-apache-sqoop-in-google-cloud-dataproc-4056b8fa2600), but it assumes that users have *GCP VPC* (which I did not intend on purchasing).

So my question is:

- Without this VPC connection, would the cloud dataproc cluster know how to get the data from the DB on our local network using the  [job submission API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/submit)?
- How would this work if so (perhaps I am do not understand enough about how Hadoop jobs work / get data)?
- Some other way if not?

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible. How coud cloud dataproc connect to your local network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using [VPC/VPN](https://cloud.google.com/hybrid-connectivity/) you will not be able to grant Dataproc access to your local DB.

Instead of using VPC, you can use VPN if it meets your needs better: https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/

Only other option that you have is to open up your local DB to Internet so Dataproc will be able to access it without VPC/VPN, but this is inherently insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the GCS connector on-prem might work in this case. It will not require VPC/VPN.